# Не перехватываются ошибки window.onerror в Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В index.html добавил перехватчик ошибок window.onerror который должен отправлять запрос на бэк с ошибкой для логирования.
Если в консоли прописать ошибку н-р setTimeout(function() { notThere(); }, 0); он ее успешно перехватит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако ошибки н-р TypeError когда вызываем toString на null, window.onerror не срабатывает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же выявил зависимость когда перехватывает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не перехватывает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без кода сложно ориентироваться что конкретно у вас не так.
Наверно вам нужно обработать данную ошибку со стороны экземпляров Vue

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.config.errorHandler = (err, vm, info) => {
  //Vue.config.errorHandler фиксирует ошибки, характерные для экземпляров Vue
};
```

Для перехвата сторонних ошибок, которые возникают вне экземпляра Vue:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  //some code
};
```

Ну и в версии 2.5.0 и выше есть хуки **errorBoundaries** и **errorCaptured**

Comment: похоже на правду. добавил скрины в вопрос. Где мне нужно разместить Vue.config.errorHandler ? чтобы на всех компонентах отрабатывал ?

Comment: Спасибо) сработало, поместил в main.js и все ок

Comment: Только увидел можно в main.js, можно было через родительский компонент если такой есть через хук errorCaptured

Answer (score 1):

> ошибки н-р TypeError когда вызываем toString на null, window.onerror не срабатывает

Давай проверим... Все вроде срабатывает.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
window.addEventListener('error', e => {
    console.log('Ошибка - ', e.message)
})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
const v = null
console.log(v.toString())

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Всё так же.. добавил скрины в вопрос. Именно исключения которые возникают в компонентах Vue  у меня в async mounted()  как будто не доходят в index.html

Comment: @Greg9303, будет более продуктивно если ты так же как и у меня сделаешь некий тестовый пример, на котором будет проявляться твоя проблема. ;)